# Can't Use Audio in One Application Because Another Has Taken Full Use of Sound Card

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, music, soundcard

One of the applications I'm trying to use tells me that the audio device is not available. Is it possible to check what applications are using the sound card at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line,

```
man lsof
sudo lsof +D /dev/snd
```

will list all the open files in `/dev/snd`, and which program has them open. See also `man fuser`.